# What is the problem with my async program

Tags: python, web-scraping, async-await

I am webscraping.i implement both sync and async version of these  codes and they give exact same execution time result.

**Getting some data from website**

```py
    async def __get_functions(self):
        data = []
        html = self.get_html_data(URL)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, self.PARSER_MODE)
        lists = soup.findAll(**HTML_TAGS["FUNCTION_LIST"])
        for ul in lists:
            li_items = ul.findAll("li")
            tasks = [asyncio.create_task(self.get_info(li)) for li in li_items]
            done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)
        self.save_as_json(data)
```

**here simply i go to other page and scrape other data**

```py
    async def get_info(self, li):
        a = li.find("a")
        name = a.text       
        href = fr"https://examplewebsite.com/{a.get('href')}"
        info = self.__get_function_data(href)
        data.append({"Name": name, **info})
```

**Getting second page data**

```py
    def __get_function_data(self, href):
        html = self.get_html_data(href)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, self.PARSER_MODE)
        data = [self.check_each_info(soup, key) for key in [
            "FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION",
            "FUNCTION_SYNTAX",
            "VERSION",
            "ARGS",
            "RETURN"]]
        clean_data = [*map(self.get_clean_text, data)]
        data = dict(zip(["desc", "syntax", "version", "args", "return"], clean_data))
        return data
```

**helper method to get raw html text**

```py
    @classmethod
    def get_html_data(cls, url):
        response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
        return response.content
```

**Start point**

```py
    def start(self):
        asyncio.run(self.__get_functions())
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there how `get_html_data` method looks like?

Comment: @AndrejKesely i did.

Comment: Thanks! I see the problem there. Now `get_html_data` uses `requests` which is synchronous library. Make the `get_html_data` async (use for example `aiohttp`) and you should see decrease in runtime. Don't forget to put `await` to right places (like `html = await self.get_html_data(href)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely but i create coroutines and if i do not get wrong they run each at the same time why sync code impacts overall performance since all runs parallel

Comment: Yes, because now `requests.get` blocks the whole program, so now you run your tasks synchronously. It doesn't run parallel.

Comment: @AndrejKesely thanks i will look up async programming i mix async and multi-threading

Answer (score 1):

thanks @AndrejKesely in comments the problem is request library is sync library so whenever program calls request lib method then whole program stops due to it is not async method.